# How can I draw periodic shapes along horizontal axis?

Tags: periodic-functions

I have [Approximating Pi](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hmcutwfumj) shape that simply I want to repeat It periodically along horizontal axis like, below image:

[image]

then I want to cut negative parts of the vertical axis:

[image]

Comment: you should be able to (a) use as f(x) cosine function as starting point, but plot the maximum of 0 and f(x) ...to get the segmented nature, let me think

Comment: so above the cosine half-period has 5 segments ...

Comment: @phdmba7of12 that's right I know max(cos(x),0) but my big problem Is that I don't know how can I repeat this shapes periodically

Comment: Isn't this question about art, not math?

Comment: @tparker no because I want use y value of shape like [this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3b/Circle_cos_sin.gif) in my code, so I don't need shape.

Answer (score 0):

Your figure is a regular $2n$-gon with $n=4$.

Following the usual orientation, we start with the point $(1,0)$, then we have $n-1$ points on the upper half plane and then the point $(-1,0)$.
For each $k\in\{0,1,\dots,n\}$ let

$$z_k=\exp\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)=
\underbrace{\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}_{x_k}
+i\,\underbrace{\sin\left(\frac{k\pi}{n}\right)}_{y_k}$$

Hence, one period of your function $f$ lies in $[-1,1]$, and for each $k$ with $1\leq k \leq n$ and each $x\in[x_{k},x_{k-1}]$ there is a unique $t_x$ such that $x=t_x\,x_k+(1-t_x)\,x_{k-1}$.
Indeed, we have

$$t_x = \frac{x_{k-1}-x}{x_{k-1}-x_k}$$

Then, for each such $x$ we have that

$$f(x)= t_x\, y_k + (1-t_x)\,y_{k-1}
$$

Finally, $f$ can be extended periodically for all $x\in \mathbb R\setminus[-1,1]$ via $f(x+1)=f(x)$.

Comment: thanks can you give me [desmos](https://www.desmos.com/) because I can't understand this :)

Comment: No, I do not know about desmos and it is frankly not needed to answer your question.

Comment: Anyway thanks, I requested executable version because programmers always like to quickly test.I will test your formula and if worked I'll accept.